# Last deployment information not avaialble - cpanel

Tags: gitlab, cpanel

I am new to cpanel repository. I have cloned my gitlab repository into cpanel by following these instructions

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/Guide+to+Git+-+Set+Up+Access+to+Private+Repositories

After cloning the repository into cpanel I tried deploying latest changes to my cpanel repository by following these videos

**Automatic Deployment**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18tXFctuqQ0

**Manual Deployment**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFyvGkE5zbQ

During manual deployment when I click on `Deploy Head Commit` button I get the following message

`The deployement you triggered is complete`

[image]

**but when I check my cpanel repository nothing updates.**

Under manage repository section of my cpanel, I still see the old commit but not the latest one.

*Note: My gitlab repository is being updated with latest commit*

**.cpanel.yml**

```
---
deployment:
  tasks:
    - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/myuser/public_html/mypath
    - /bin/cp * $DEPLOYPATH
```

I don't have much knowledge of these things. please ask for additional info if needed

Answer (score 1):

for anyone else facing the similar challenge in future.
instead of using  `- /bin/cp * $DEPLOYPATH`, please replace it with `-/bin/cp -R * $DEPLOYPATH` to be able to copy all files and sub-directories from the github repository to the cpanel